# Find mkv files only when rar file is in same folder?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, find

Can i use find command to list all .mkv files that are in a folder with a .rar present

**Example:**

```
TV/Show1/
TV/Show1/file1.mkv
TV/Show2/
TV/Show2/file2.rar
TV/Show2/file2.mkv
```

**Output**

```
TV/Show2/file2.mkv
```

I want to find and list all such files recursivly for all folders inside TV. Is that possible?

Comment: Looks like there is no OOTB way to do it.. but some way out suggested here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/633772/find-and-search-inside-all-compressed-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
find . -type -f -name '*.mkv' -exec bash -c '[ -f "${1%.*}.rar" ] && echo "$1"' _ {} \;
```

`find` will find all .mkv files and pass it to the shell script's argument 1

```sh
[ -f "${1%.*}.rar" ] && echo "$1"
```

Shell script will strip the dot extension from .mkv file passed as argument 1
`${1%.*}`, then check the stripped name .rar exist `[ -f filepath ]`.
When .rar exist, it will `echo` the name of the .mkv file from argument 1.